# wp_trim_words() does not trim the_content() in WordPress

Tags: customization, templates, excerpt

In my WordPress website, I want to show a short text of each blog_post on the custom blog template. I want to show a `Read More` button with a link to the post at the end so a user can click on that link and view the full post.

But I am always getting the whole post instead of its summary.

Here is my code:

```
$moreLink = '<a href="' . the_permalink() . '"> Read More...</a>';
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Read more"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php echo wp_trim_words( the_content(), 55, $moreLink); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I have tried different codes instead of `wp_trim_words(the_content(), 55, $moreLink);` found online with no luck. Even I have used the same line of code on another custom template and it is working fine. However, with this template, it is not working.

Am I doing any mistake in my code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem lies in this line:

```
<?php echo wp_trim_words( the_content(), 55, $moreLink); ?>
```

You call `the_content` function in there. This function prints all the content and doesn't return anything. It means that you print the content, and then pass an empty string to the `wp_trim_words`.

It should be:

```
<?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 55, $moreLink); ?>
```

**Be careful** because, as described in [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content), `get_the_content()` does not pass the content through the 'the_content' filter. This means it won't execute shortcodes. If you want to get exactly what `the_content()` prints, you have to use

```
<?php
$my_content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
echo wp_trim_words( $my_content, 55, $moreLink);
?>
```

I suggest to also use [`wp_strip_all_tags()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_strip_all_tags), otherwise you may have problems with open tags that have been trimmed.

Full example:

```
<?php
$my_content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
$my_content = wp_strip_all_tags($my_content);
echo wp_trim_words( $my_content, 55, $moreLink);
?>
```

Comment: It works but instead of the actual content, it shows me the post shortcode like [this](http://rchto.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/ToShare.jpg).

Comment: @Mr. Cariol Thanks for your answer. The solution you provided is working fine.